# Setting default selection in DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Using the new ASP.NET Model Binding where I wire the `SelectMethod` property of my control (a `DropDownList` in this case) to a public function defined in the code-behind, how do I set the default value of `SelectedIndex` for that `DropDownList`? I tried doing this in `Page_Load()`, but it looks like the SelectMethod is invoked only after Page_Load() has completed. What's my way forward?

Answer (score 0):

there should be a `SelectedValue` property you can leverage.
Post your code snippet for additional assistance.